# Passing JavaScript array to input in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, arrays

I'm trying to pass an array from JavaScript to a PHP input. I want to pass my array as an array inside my input, not a string.

My array is this:

```
["0_1","0_2"]
```

And this is how I pass my array to my input:

```
$('#movefile_id').val(JSON.stringify(allfiledata));
```

Can I pass the array to the input file without making it a string?

Comment: you can't

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1696877/how-to-set-a-value-to-a-file-input-in-html

Comment: I see, I'll just have to make do with strings.

Comment: but you are referring to file input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

read this:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify

you can convert your array to JSON

```
var arrayJavascript = JSON.stringify(["0_1","0_2"]);
```

and with PHP, read this:

http://php.net/manual/es/function.json-decode.php

```
$arrayPHP = json_decode($_POST["arrayJavascript"]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the step by step process given below

1- Covert the Javascript Array to JSON

2- Post that JSON string to PHP using jquery post or jquery get

This is possible through only using Ajax. Because javscript is a Client side language and PHP is a server side language.We can only connect both using Ajax.